# how to replace multiple types of delimiters with a comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have the following string in a text file

`SCF Done:  E(RHF) =  -100.055079426     A.U. after    9 cycles`

The goal is to convert this string into csv type data by getting rid of all the unwanted white space and replacing it with commas. Here is what I have so far

```
import csv


f = open('testfile1','r')

x = f.readlines()

s = []

for line in x:

    line = line.strip(' ')

    line = line.replace('  ',',')

    s.append(line)

csvex = csv.writer(open('name.csv', "w"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

csvex.writerow(s)
```

The code gives me the following output

```
"SCF Done:,E(RHF) =,-100.055079426,, A.U. after,,9 cycles
"
```

I want the code to give me the following output

```
"SCF,Done:,E(RHF),=,-100.055079426,A.U.,after,9,cycles"
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csvwriter.writerow` accepts iterable (list, tuple, etc.) ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow)).

This script read input file line by line, split the line and write the line to csv file.

If `file.txt` contains:

```
SCF Done:  E(RHF) =  -100.055079426     A.U. after    9 cycles
```

Then this script:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f_out, \
    open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    csvex = csv.writer(f_out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for line in f_in:
        csvex.writerow(line.strip().split())
```

Writes csv file `file.csv` with content like this:

```
SCF,Done:,E(RHF),=,-100.055079426,A.U.,after,9,cycles
```

Comment: awesome! If I am not being a bother, I have 2 questions. First, I did not see where you inserted `,` as the delimiter. How did python know what to insert after stripping the white space? Also, what exactly is `QUOTE_MINIMAL` achieving in the code.

Comment: @JM8 the `csv` module is writing the csv file with comma as default delimiter. `QUOTE_MINIMAL` means that if there's delimiter or other quote char in tbe string, it will quote those field. More info here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

file = open("testfile1",'r')
x=file.readlines()

s=[]
for line in x:

    line = line.strip(' ')
    line = ",".join(line.split())
    s.append(line)

csvex = csv.writer(open("name.csv", "w"), quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

csvex.writerow(s)
```

",".join(line.split()) is the function which splits and then insert ',' at every space